# <input type="file"> is undefined after simple file select

Tags: html, forms, file, input, undefined

I have:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
```

Clicking the "Choose file" button allows me to select a file using Finder/Explorer/whatever. When I click "Open" and return to my form, the text "No file chosen" remains.

If i check the value using:

```
$("#fileToUpload").change(function() {
        console.log($("#fileToUpload").value);
    });
```

The value is undefined. I am tearing my hair out because this is so, so simple and it's not working. What can I be missing?

Comment: This has reared its head again. The code is at:

http://vzaarsupport.com/alasdair/demos/api_uploader_H5_dev/

If you click the "Choose file" button and choose a file, the text "No file chosen" remains even after the file is chosen.

How can something so simple be so hard? :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery objects don't have the `.value` property. They have a `.val()` method.

So you want

```
console.log($("#fileToUpload").val());
```

Comment: No, they have a `val()` method.

Comment: Apologies. Switching between JS and jQuery...

I changed the jQuery to `console.log($("#fileToUpload").val());` and the filename is now correctly reported but the `<input>` still displays "No file chosen"

Comment: I tried explicitly setting the value of `fileToUpload` from the `$("#fileToUpload").val()` and i get an error: `Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`. But, the file selector now displays the selected filename!